# How to add action when Trailing Swipe Action cancelled (Swift 5)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my project I use trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt func. And I also use selectRow func when I need. If my cell is selected and I use swipe on it and then I cancelled it (swipe from left to right), my cell doesn't selected again. Where can I fix it (use selectRow again)?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "") { [weak self] (contextualAction, view, boolValue) in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.deleteRow(at: indexPath)
        }
        deleteAction.image = UIImage(systemName: "trash")
        
        let swipeActions = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
        
        return swipeActions
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath?) {
  //Get the cell's indexPath (be aware of the optional argument and threat it the way you want)
  let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!)
  //Use the cell to the changes you need
}
```

Also you can use an animation if you want to achieve a smooth effect.

Comment: Great answer just what I needed

Answer (score 0):

you're not calling the completion handler. According to the API documentation it is necessary to call the completion handler to indicate whether the operation was successful.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
            let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "") { _, _, complete in
                // remove object from your array..
                self.arrayName.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                //reload the table to avoid index out of bounds crash..
                self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
                complete(true)
            }
            
            deleteAction.image = UIImage(named: "trash")
            let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
            configuration.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = true
            return configuration
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I understand, I can use 'complete' like a flag to select row again, if deleteAction doesn't complete?

Comment: No complete is basically a Completion Handler here. Completion handlers get passed to a function as an argument and then called when that function is done. Please read more about them here. https://medium.com/@dhavalkansara51/completion-handler-in-swift-with-escaping-and-nonescaping-closures-1ea717dc93a4

Comment: Sorry, but I still do not understand where I should use selectRow again if I hide the swipe action menu.

Comment: Im sorry but you first select the row and then Use swipe on it? Well to Perform Swipe, there is actually no need to select it first.

Comment: No, I am highlighting the row for a different reason. I create a music player and thus I show which track is playing right now.